# Is It Possible To Archive a UIPickerView Using encodeObject?

Tags: ios, uipickerview, nscoding

I want to restore my view state, and my view has a`UIPickerView`.

`UIPickerView` looks to me like it has graphics components, namely the background wheel image. I know that`UIImage` cannot be archived. Anything with an image, like`UIImageView`, you have to first set the image to`nil`before you can encode it.

However,`UIPickerView`is`NSCoding`compliant. That means that`encodeObject`and`decodeObject`should work.

They don't though. I mean, they don't cause any errors. But after decoding, you get the`UIPickerView`without any images. It doesn't look good!

Here's a before and after shot just to prove I'm not going mad:

**Before**

[image: Before]

**After**

[image: After]

Now, I know that I could simply store the current user selection, and recreate the view by invoking the picker's`selectRow`method. But really, I'm curious. Why is`UIPickerView` `NSCoding` compliant if it isn't really and you can't do anything further to get the background wheel image back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seemed to have answered your own question. `UIImageView` conforms to `NSCoding` yet does not save the `UIImage` (obviously since the image is saved elsewhere) so why would you expect `UIPickerView` to behave any differently?

From what I've read (although never done) `NSCoding` on `UIViews` is used to save state (frame, visibility, etc) not the actual view. Although a little inconsistent on Apple's part, it seems logical to me, since the entire UIView library is already in iOS, why waste time & space reserializing all that data?

The only thing that would be gained from your proposed solution would be a little less boilerplate code (for resetting the view) and has the potential to slowing the reading/writing of the objects down (because it has to account for the images)

Comment: my point is that you can't reconstruct a UIPickerView, so why make it NSCoding compliant?

Comment: Kevin explained it. NSCoding doesn't archive *everything* as a rule, merely the data necessary to reconstruct it.

Comment: I think you are reading too much into what NSCoding is suppose to do. From Apple's documentation:"This capability provides the basis for archiving." Never says it is the "one stop shop" you are trying to make it.

Comment: To answer your question directly, it's probably because it inherited from `UIView`. So, when you call `initWithCoder:` it is probably just getting passed to `super` so `UIView` does instantiate itself (ie the previous state) and nothing else. So, you are basically getting a `UIView` cast as a `UIPicker`.

That is all just speculation though.